# markov process and markov chains

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I have learned that Markov processes are stochastic processes possessing certain mathematical properties (memoryless, etc). My question is, if you say that a process is Markov, is it automatic (as a form of cause and effect) that one can be able to model the process using the Markov Chains? (with the transition probability matrix that has a columns/or rows having a sum of one)?

Your insights would be helpful.

Comment: One cannot model a Markov process as anything, whether a Markov chain or something else, since a Markov process is already a model.

Comment: A continuous process that has the markov property would not be modeled as a markov chain, but might be referred to as a markov process.

Comment: So what is the difference between Markov Chains and Markov Process?

Comment: For some authors, "chains" refers to families of random variables indexed by some discrete set, for example $\mathbb N$, and "processes" to families of random variables indexed by some continuous set, for example $\mathbb R_+$.

Comment: @cgo, not all chains represent a graph, they can be 'trees' with transition probabilities that end on 'leaves' although each step is conducted according to a Markovian process till termination of state changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can model it as Markovian by default, yes, because of the properties mentioned. As long as the properties are satisfied the model can be defined for the particular case, and the chain transitions through states can be modeled. Whether all Markov chains will be useful or insightful is not guaranteed. It does not even mean that they are the only paradigm in which to model the transitions. Although it might not be the most suited paradigm for every problem definition which satisfies the requirements, it can still be performed. (the transition probabilities must sum to 1 for each state)